# Relative path from a yaml to a markdown not working correctly. Per the absolute files I moved the path by 2 levels but doesnt work :(

Tags: yaml, markdown, relative-path

My CWD is **C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\RepoName.config\item1\yaml1.yaml**
From this yaml file I am trying to reference the markdown in this path. C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\RepoName\md1.md.

I tried the relative URL as - ../../md1.md, since it needs to go 2 levels up. This did not work, please help!